# StaticInjectorError for CookieService

Tags: javascript, angular

I need to use CookieService on my app. When I inject the class using

```
constructor(private cookieService: CookieService) {
```

I get the following error:

```
core.js:1673 ERROR Error: Uncaught (in promise): Error: StaticInjectorError(AppModule)[CookieService]:
```

I can use the Cookie service by creating an instance within the method...but first I want to understand why I can't apply inversion of control for this service.

Answer (score 1):

This could be due to one of the following reasons :

1. You have not provided `CookieService` in your module
2. If it is `provided` in a different `module`, then you have to import that `module` in your `module`.
3. Check if you have added `@Injectable()` decorator to `CookieService`.

Comment: I import...also, cookie service is this one:
https://www.npmjs.com/package/ngx-cookie-service

Comment: Document says to add `providers: [ CookieService ]` in your `AppModule`. Have you done that?